# How do i loop over a geometric sequence. i need to loop some function over 1, 2, 4, 8, 16

Tags: python, arrays, loops, iteration

My code is

```
T=np.empty()
for N in range ("some gemetric numbers: 1,2,4,8,16):
    T[N]= trap(f1,a,b,N)
```

This is what the program looks like

Comment: Then don't use `range`. `for item in some_sequence:` is perfectly fine

Comment: **range** takes up to three parameters, `range(start, stop, step)`, which is great when you know at which value the loop should **start** and possibly **stop**. However the **step** value is a fixed integer interval. It is therefor not suited for a geometric series. [Try out range yourself here.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/showpython.asp?filename=demo_ref_range3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With generators:

```
def geom_generator(max_number):
  i = 1
  while i < max_number:
    yield i
    i = i*2

for i in geom_generator(max_number=1000): # just a random sample
  # do something
  print (i)
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either loop over a fixed sequence:

```
for n in [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]:
    # do stuff with n
```

or you can generate the sequence dynamically:

```
n = 1
while True:
    # do stuff with n
    n *= 2
```

Be careful as the 2nd example will loop forever unless you `break` on a particular condition.

Answer (score 0):

a tricky approach:

```
from math import log

x = 1
coeff = 2
for i in range(0, int(log(1000, coeff)) + 1):
    print(x)
    x *= coeff
```